# echo css background image url not functioning causes no display

Tags: php, html, css

I'm encountering other form of problem regarding background-image url in css.
The destination of my image is in includes/img/messaging.png. my problem is i put css on echo so here is my code

```
logs.php
    echo '<div style="width: auto; margin-left: 250px; 
    margin-right: 5px; padding-right:8px; border-bottom: 2px solid; 
    border-top: 2px solid; border-color: #ebebeb; border-radius: 8px; 
    padding-bottom: 10px; padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 15px; text-align:left; font-size:0.8em; color:#FFFFFF; background-image: url("../includes/img/messaging.png");">' . 
    '<div style="font-weight:bold;">' . "You" . "</div>message: " . $messages->msg . "<br>" . '<div style="font-size: 0.6em;">'. "Sent : " . $messages->dt . "</div>" . '</div>';
```

as you can see the destination of my image was right. But why it doesn't display something. i have 2 folders pages and includes. logs.php is located at pages/logs.php and the images is in includes/img/messaging.php so my echo was in right directory accessing the image

Comment: Try this "includes/img/messaging.png"

Comment: Is the above code in the same directory like the `include` folder? If yes you should remove `...` from the path, since it navigates to the parent folder first.

Comment: Check the browser's developer tools, you will see right away if the path is right or not. And you should post the generated html instead of the php as this is not related to php.

Comment: is the `includes` folder at root level of the site or nested within another folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your line as below:-

```
background-image: url(\'../includes/img/messaging.png\');
```

and if you are a linux user then make sure you have given permission to image.

Hope this will help you :)